# Google Music Manager doesn't displayed

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xmonad, google-music

How can I configure my Xmonad config that Google music manager is displayed?

I cannot open the options window from the context menu.

Has anybody any idea why it does not display?

Comment: I think that you need to be a little bit more accurate with what you are trying to say? I cannot understand what you are trying to attempt to do here. Honestly, if English is not your first language then try and write more sentences and throw them through Google Translate.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this answer in the askubuntu foum
https://askubuntu.com/a/236942/41186

I deleted the google-musicmanager folder in .config and after the setup everything works like expected